# Understanding and generalizing $P(X \in B)$ for any subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we flip three fair coins, and let $X$ be the number of heads showing. Write a formula for $P(X \in B)$, for any subset $B$ of the real numbers.

I first started by computing $P(X = x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ where I found that $P(X = 0) = P(X = 3) = \frac{3}{8}$, $P(X = 1) = P(X = 2) = \frac{1}{8}$ and P(X = x) = 0 for $x \notin \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, but I am not sure how to go about writing the formula, and quite frankly, I don't understand what $P(X \in B)$ really means. Could someone please help me clear my doubts for those two questions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you get $P[X=0]=3/8$?  That looks like a minor mistake.  For example can you compute $P[X \in [1.5, 8] \cup [-9, -6] \cup \{88.7\}]$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write $\frac{1}{8}$. As for your questions, wouldn't we need to split every set and compute it separately? ($P(X \in [1.5, 8]) + P(X \in [-9, -6]) + P(X = 88.7)$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indicator function is defined $1_A(x)=I(x\in A)=\begin{cases}1&x\in A\\
0 &x\not\in A\end{cases}$

Here we can do

$$\begin{split}P(X\in B)&=P(X=0)1_{B}(0)+P(X=1)1_B(1)+P(X=2)1_B(2)+P(X=3)1_B(3)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^3 P(X=i)1_B(i)\end{split}$$

Comment: Thanks! Just an aside question, when would knowing $P(X \in B)$ be useful?

Comment: @user62487108 It could be useful if $B\subseteq \{0,1,2,3\}$ then you would see the prob that $X$ takes on one of those values but it has not much use if $B$ contains decimals or numbers that are not possible outcomes